# Unknown modifier '/' error in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
preg_replace('/http:///ftp:///', 'https://', $value);
```

`http://` and `ftp://` inside `$value` should be replaced with `https://`

This code gives error:

```
preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/'
```

**What is a true regex for this task?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a different delimiter, say `#`:

```
preg_replace('#http://|ftp://#', 'https://', $value);
```

or (less recommended) escape every occurrence of the delimiter in the regex:

```
preg_replace('/http:\/\/|ftp:\/\//', 'https://', $value);
```

Also you are searching for the pattern `http:///ftp://` which really does not make much sense, may be you meant `http://|ftp://`.

You can make your regex shorter as:

```
preg_replace('#(?:http|ftp)#', 'https', $value);
```

**Understanding the error:** `Unknown modifier '/'`

In your regex `'/http:///ftp:///'`, the first `/` is considered as starting delimiter and the `/` after the `:` is considered as the ending delimiter. Now we know we can provide modifier to the regex to alter its default behavior. Some such modifiers are:

- `i` : to make the matching case
  insensitive
- `m` : multi-line searching

But what PHP sees after the closing delimiter is another `/` and tries to interpret it as a modifier but fails, resulting in the error.

`preg_replace` returns the altered string.

```
$value = 'http://foo.com';
$value = preg_replace('#http://|ftp://#', 'https://', $value);
// $value is now https://foo.com
```

Comment: Are you collecting the return value of `preg_replace` as I've shown above ?

Answer (score 1):

Use another delimiter character, like '#', for instance.

```
preg_replace('#/http://|ftp://#', 'https://', $value);
```

And do not confuse / and |

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('!(http://|ftp://)!', 'https://', $value);
```

Long story: Regexp needs to be enclosed in delimiters, and those have to be unique inside the whole regexp. If you want to use /, then the remaining /-s inside the regexp need to be escaped. This however makes the syntax look a bit ugly. Luckily you can use any character as delimiter. ! works fine, as will other characters.

The rest of the regexp just lists two options, either of which will be replaced with the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('|http:\/\/ftp:\/\/', 'https://|', $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
preg_replace('-(http|ftp)://-', 'https://', $value);
```

Or

```
preg_replace('/(http|ftp):\/\//', 'https://', $value);
```