# php regex Unknown modifier '/'

Tags: php, regex

Text:

```
<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_28300"
```

My regex:

```
/<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_(.*?)"/mis
```

Code:

```
$regex = '/<a href="'.$text.'"><img id="img_(.*?)"/mis';
preg_match($regex, $text, $C);
```

Error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/'
```

Comment: What's your actual regex?

Comment: OP already posted the regex.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Because there are many forward slashes in your `text` variable, i suggest you to use a different modifier.

Comment: if you combine `<a href` with `$text`, you should got two `a href`'s.

Comment: @Kubra what are you trying to achieve? What's your expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown modifier '/' error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719915/unknown-modifier-error-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the slashes (`/`) in the regex:

```
/<a href="http:\/\/from.ae\/cameras-photo\/digital-cameras\/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_(.*?)"/mis
```

Because you used `/` as your delimiter, PHP assumes everything after the second `/` is a modifier. In this case, that's another `/`, which is not a valid modifier.

You can do the escaping with [**`preg_quote`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), like this:

```
$text = '<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_28300"';
$regex = '/'.preg_quote('<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_', '/').'(.*?)"/mis';
var_dump($regex);
var_dump( preg_match($regex, $text) );
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/P9DrEC)

An even simpler solution, as pointed out in the comments, is just to use a different delimiter. I'm fond of `~`, but any character will work:

```
$text = '<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_28300"';
$regex = '~<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_(.*?)"~mis';
var_dump($regex);
var_dump( preg_match($regex, $text) );
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ljz7Bq)

Comment: `$regex = '<a href="'.$text.'"><img id="img_(.*?)"';` like this?

Comment: @Kubra: It's better if you take the problem identification made here and use it to write your _own_ code solution. Stack Overflow is not a magic code generator that does your programming work for you.

Comment: @Kubra Please see my edit; you can do the escaping with [**`preg_quote`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Comment: now it has two hrefs.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, I'm not sure exactly what OP is going for, either. I have tried to clarify.

Comment: Quoting is good but using a different delimiter is even better because it keeps the RE clean. However, +1 for mentioning about `preq_quote()` because sometimes one simply cannot avoid it (when the RE is produced using data from external sources, f.e.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use another delimiter than `/` which can be in regex.

Updated regex could be, for example this one, with `~` as a delimiter:

```
~<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_(.*?)"~mis
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `\K` with a different php delimiter.

```
$text = '<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_28300"';
preg_match('~<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_\K[^"]*~mis', $text, $out);
echo $out[0];
```

Output:

```
28300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<a href="http://from.ae/cameras-photo/digital-cameras/samsung-es95-white"><img id="img_28300"';

preg_match('#<img id="img_(.*?)"#', $text,$match);
print_r($match);
echo $match[1];
```